# Open text files in matlab and save them from matlab

Tags: matlab, fopen, text-files

I have a big text file containing data that needs to be extracted and inserted into a new text file. I possibly need to store this data in an cell/matrix array ?

But for now, the question is that I am trying to test a smaller dataset, to check if the code below works.

I have a code in which it opens a text file, scans through it and replicates the data and saves it in another text file called, "output.txt".

Problem : It doesn't seem to save the file properly. It just shows an empty array in the text file, such as this `" [] "`. The original text file just contains string of characters.

```
%opens the text file and checks it line by line.
fid1 = fopen('sample.txt');
tline = fgetl(fid1);
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline);
    tline = fgetl(fid1);
end
fclose(fid1);


% save the sample.txt file to a new text fie
fid = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s %s\n', fid1);
fclose(fid);

% view the contents of the file
type exp.txt
```

Where do i go from here ?

Comment: What OS ? 32 or 64 bit? This page its helpful. Go to the increase swap part http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1106.html

Comment: It is a 64bit system and what do i set paging file size to be, custom size, system managed size, or no paging file?

Comment: please present with the steps you did. Did you write some code to open text files, or did you use the editor to open the text file ?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code that i have used.

Comment: You have to increase the size, to do so it has to be custom sized to increase from the default. This shouldn't be an issue on a 64 bit machine if you have a fair amount of ram. So I would respond to pavans question

Comment: Try using the fopen function. Read all the data in with that and then perform your manipulation. Then clear it out of memory using clear.

Comment: @Pavan I have presented the code in my question and i have called out the function in the command window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a good practice to read an input file by loading all of its contents to memory at once. This way the file size you're able to read is limited by the amount of memory on the machine (or by the amount of memory the OS is willing to allocate to a single process).

Instead, use fopen and its related function in order to read the file line-by-line or char-by- char.

For example,

```
fid1 = fopen('sample.txt', 'r');
fid = fopen('output.txt', 'w');

tline = fgetl(fid1);
while ischar(tline)
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', tline);
    tline = fgetl(fid1);    
end

fclose(fid1);
fclose(fid);

type output.txt
```

Of course, if you know in advance that the input file is never going to be large, you can read it all at once using by textread or some equivalent function.

Comment: Do i need a function to open the file and then from there call it in the command window ? If so, how would i call the function in the m file? Thank you

Comment: I suggest you'll write all of your code in an m-file and call only it from the command-line. Thus, the m-file should include code similar to what I gave in the example with the addition of another fopen for the output file and the logic for writing into it inside the loop.

Comment: Basically, I want to open a file, store in a cell or matrix array. From there, i would like to manipulate the data as i need it to. Then save that manipulated data into another text file. How do i go about doing that ?

Comment: Does your file fit into memory?

Comment: yes it does. I used the code above and called it in the command window. It took about 5minutes for it all to appear because I am dealing with a huge number of characters in the files.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it and see where I am going wrong in the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `textread`, it reads data from a text file and stores it as a matrix or a Cell array. At the end of the day, I assume you would want the data to be stored in a variable to manipulate it as required. Once you are done manipulating, open a file using `fopen` and use `fprintf` to write data in the format you want.

Comment: Basically, I want to open a file, store in a cell or matrix array. From there, i would like to manipulate the data as i need it to. Then save that manipulated data into another text file. How do i go about doing that ?