# Reading from .txt file to array one line at a time (Matlab or C). "Insufficient memory" to load the whole file at once using 'A=load()'.

Tags: c, arrays, matlab

I have a .txt file containing 1000 rows and 100000 columns. A 10GB text file, of simulation results (real numbers) that I need to analyse.

My data is of the form:   `[0.5 0.3 0.45 .. ;
                         0.4 0.22 0.21587 .. ;
                         0.1359 1.054 1.1 ... ]`
(separated by spaces and lines)

If I try loading (in Matlab) the entire file into a matrix at once using `A=load('Data.txt')`, I get an error message: "Insufficient memory", which I assume means - RAM (right?).

I wish to read than only one line from the file at a time, into a 1d array. How do I do that? 
I already tried different versions of `A=load('Data.txt')(1,:)` or `A=load('Data.txt'(1,:))` etc.

An answer in C code code would also be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you intend to do after loading it?

Comment: If you only want the first line and are on a UNIX platform. Use `head -1 Data.txt > first.txt` or `sed '1q' Data.txt > first.txt`. Then in Matlab `A=load('first.txt')`. But as @mohit asked, what are you intending to do?

Comment: @mohit : Thanks for your help. Well, each line is data taken from one run of the simulation. I can analyse each line on it's own then. The analysis is a bit to hard to explain here, but say for example I wanted to get the cumulative sum of each line, and in the end get a long array which holds all the sums.

Comment: @Timothy Brown and Schorsch : I work on Matlab in Windows.  I have no problem to take my data though, and write a program in C to analyse it (~ Don't know any other programing languages...) . The goal would be the same : read each line at a time from the data,  and - calculate it's sum. OK - to make it simpler : not the CUMSUM, but just the sum of all it's numbers.

Comment: You can use `fgetl` and then `sscanf` in Matlab to read line by line.

Comment: Can you give an example for the code? How do I use these commands ?

Comment: @user1611107 Please read the documentation of [fgetl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) and [sscanf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html)

Comment: Is it possible for the OP to use sscanf for non-standard strings like he indicated?  I had the impression that sscanf was only really useful for tab/comma/etc type of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If efficiency is not too much of a concern, you can use an eval statement.

```
fid = fopen('output.txt');  % Open the file
numRun = 10; % The number of simulations
for ii = 1:numRun
    ln = fgetl(fid);
    eval( sprintf('a=%s;', ln) );

    % Do stuff
end
```

However, I think that a better way for you to do it would be to give each run its own special file, and then read that like normal.  That way you don't have to worry about ghost variables from eval statements or overall eval overhead.

```
fid = fopen('output.txt');  % Open the file
numRun = 10; % The number of simulations

for ii = 1:numRun
    ofid = fopen(sprintf('output%i.txt', ii), 'w')
    ln = fgetl(fid); % Read the line
    fprintf( ofid, ln );
    fclose( fid );
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think that splitting up the file into subfiles will really provide any more ease or speed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll check it and write here if it worked. One question though: "ghost variables from eval statements or overall eval overhead.". What do u mean?

Comment: If you are referring to the getting ease or speed over the eval statement, I don't really think that for a one off deal you would get any improvement.  However in my experience when you have large datasets and you are doing TDD (or similar) or you have a lot of processing to do, MATLAB doesn't do too well releasing resources after eval statements since it has to compile eval statements into resident memory on the fly.  WRT the ease, I find debugging much more difficult when there are eval statements.  Not too mention whenever you return to the code later.

Comment: `eval` takes a string and compiles it on the fly which is different than standard matlab code.  See the MATLAB [eval docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5) Since the string that `eval` acts on can change, the MATLAB compiler cannot precompile it.  Thus if you have a lot of eval statements (say in a loop), it can cost you a lot in terms of computational time and resources (overhead).  Ghost variables are variables which can appear in a workspace without having an obvious assignment, making it hard to track problems related to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689445/2419003). If your file is that big, you should not try to load it all at once. You should read it line by line. If this still doesn't work, you should take a look at the [csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) function.

Edit:
Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440592/fastest-matlab-file-reading) could be quite helpful

2nd Edit:
Try the [Matfile io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9135329/2419003)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
fid = fopen('Data.txt');
while~feof(fid)
    line = fgetl(fid);
    C = textscan(line, '%f %f %f', 'Delimiter', ';');
    data = cell2mat(C);
    ... Do you processing below
end
```

This will process the data line by line.  I'm also assuming that you data is delimited by the `;` char, and that you know the length of each line hence the (`%f %f %f`).  For example, this:

```
0.5 0.3 0.45; 0.4 0.22 0.21587; 0.1359 1.054 1.1
```

will turn into this:

```
0.5000    0.3000    0.4500
0.4000    0.2200    0.2159
0.1359    1.0540    1.1000
```

---

> The goal would be the same : read each line at a time from the data, and - calculate it's sum. – [user1611107](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611107/user1611107)

If you're looking to find the sum of each line, you can add the following:

```
lSum = sum(data);
```